# I want to upload a hidden file on the internal storage but i cant because its hidden. How do i unhide it?

Tags: android, permissions, root, dropbox

The file is somewhere in the data/data/appfolder/sharedprefs/ folders but these files seem to be hidden to people that didnt make the app.

I want to upload the file to dropbox but i cant because like i said the file seems to be hidden to dropbox. How can i change the file permissions so that it is no longer hidden and i can upload it to dropbox?

My app will probably need root permissions which it has. I want to upload the file using dropboxs apis for back up and restore purposes. Normally i just point to the file path and it uploads it, but its giving me a file not found error with these files.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to send the shard pref xml files?

Comment: Yeah those are the ones. I want to upload them to the users Dropbox account that they sign into. And then let the user download them again when they need and overwrite what ever copy is there. Basically back them up. Ive seen a couple of apps that do it i think but just dont know how. My app requests root privileges for users that want to use this  feature

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it's hidden, it's that other apps do not have permission to access your app's files. This is a good thing! It means your app can be the gatekeeper that provides access to those files on an as-needed basis. You don't need or want root permissions in a well-behaved app.

The correct way to provide a file to another app for use in things like ACTION_SEND intent URIs is to write a simple [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html). If you're just providing simple read-only access to a file and you don't need the ContentProvider to be queryable, this is a lot easier than it sounds.

The two ContentProvider methods you'll want to implement are `getType` and `openFile`. In openFile you can enforce access restrictions however you would like for your app, and then return a [`ParcelFileDescriptor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html) to the file.

Comment: I know that i can use contentProvider but i heard you need permission for that from the app owner. Lets just say my app is not well behaved, can i still access and overwrite those files without contentProvider?